# If $p(2x+1)=p(x^2)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $p\equiv\text{const.}$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Let $p\in \Bbb{R}[x]$ (polynomial) with $\deg(p)=n$. Suppose that $p(2x+1)=p(x^2)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove  that $p\equiv\text{const.}$

Comment: Hint: use that deg$\bigl(p(2x+1)\bigr)=n$ and deg$\bigl(p(x^2)\bigr)=2n$.

Comment: Note that all of these answers (including the above comment) depend on the fact if two polynomial functions over $\mathbb{R}$ are equal, then they must in fact be the same polynomials. This holds in general for any *infinite* field. I think this is a point to be emphasized. To prove this fact, use the the well-known result that any non-zero polynomial $P$ over a field must have at most $\operatorname{deg}(P)$ many roots.

Comment: Good point, @Prism. When I teach number theory, it can be tricky to explain that a polynomial is a *formal expression*, not a number. So the polynomials $x^5 - x$ and $0$ *are* different over $\Bbb{F}_5$, although they evaluate to the same number at each point of $\Bbb{F}_5$. And, as you note, this won't happen in an infinite field.

Comment: @Stahl: I concur :) By the way, the fact I mention above easily (by induction) extends to polynomials in several variables, provided that ground field is still infinite. This is more surprising: even with sufficiently many variables, one cannot cook up two "different looking expressions" (i.e. different polynomials) that evaluate to same number at each point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** If $p(2x + 1) = p\left(x^2\right)$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, $\deg(p(2x + 1)) = \deg\left(p\left(x^2\right)\right)$. You know $\deg p$, so what can you deduce about $\deg\left(p\left(x^2\right)\right)$?

Comment: So, $n=2n$. Thus $n=0$.

Comment: @17SI.34SA Let's look at an example: $p(x) = x$. What is $\deg\left(p\left(x^2\right)\right)$?

Comment: Yes, yes yes! Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: that was thew cleverest approach ever.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $n$ is the degree of $p$. In the lhs $x\mapsto p(2x+1)$ is still a polynomial of degree $n$ and in the rhs $x\mapsto p(x^2)$ is polynomial of degree $2n$, check both statements for yourself. These expressions must be the same by the equation. Hence the degree on both side must be equal. Which is only possible when $n=2n$ and so...